# Finding the closest value in array and remove it

Tags: java, collections

I've searched through a several similar threads with the exact problem, however I have been unable to get the code to work, I want to find the closest value in the array and then remove it, here is my code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Entertrain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Power: ");
        int power = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
        ArrayList<Integer> weight = new ArrayList<>();
        int averageWagon = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while (console.hasNextInt()) {
            weight.add(console.nextInt());

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < weight.size(); i++)
            sum += weight.get(i);

        if (sum > power) {
            averageWagon = sum / weight.size();
            //Here I want to find the closest value to averageWagon

        }
        System.out.println(averageWagon);

        System.out.println(weight);
        System.out.println(power);
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

If it would be possible to guide me to a solution, I've tried for a few hours now and I've ended with the conclusion that I seriously lack knowledge of arrays, so in any case I will put aside this and focus on arrays for now, but would be grateful for help on this one.

Comment: Maybe you should add some of the code that you have already written? Even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Power: ");
    int power = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
    ArrayList<Integer> weight = new ArrayList<>();
    int averageWagon = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (console.hasNextInt()) {
        weight.add(console.nextInt());

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < weight.size(); i++) {
        sum += weight.get(i);
    }

    if (sum > power) {
        averageWagon = sum / weight.size();
        //Here I want to find the closest value to averageWagon
        int closest = findClosestNumber(averageWagon, weight);
        System.out.println("Closest number to average: "+ closest);

    }
    System.out.println(averageWagon);

    System.out.println(weight);
    System.out.println(power);
    System.out.println(sum);

}

static int findClosestNumber(int num, List<Integer> numbers) {
    int closest = numbers.get(0);

    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (Math.abs(num - i) < Math.abs(num - closest)) {
            closest = i;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not arrays you are looking for, it is Collections. You are using ArrayList, which implements the List.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Power: ");
    int power = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
    ArrayList<Integer> weight = new ArrayList<>();
    int averageWagon = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (console.hasNextInt()) {
        weight.add(console.nextInt());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < weight.size(); i++)
        sum += weight.get(i);

    if (sum > power) {
        averageWagon = sum / weight.size();

        Integer closest = weight.get(0);
        for (Integer i: weight) {
             if (Math.abs(averageWagon - closest) > Math.abs(averageWagon - i))
                 closest = i;
        }
        weight.remove(closest);
    }
    System.out.println(averageWagon);

    System.out.println(weight);
    System.out.println(power);
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with streams:

```
int sum = weight.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

if (sum > power) {
    int avg = sum / weight.size(); // shouldn't it be double?
    weight.stream()
        .min((a, b) -> Integer.compare(Math.abs(a - avg), Math.abs(b - avg)))
        .ifPresent(weight::remove); // remove closest number from weight
}                                   // list if found (i.e. if list not empty)
```

First a stream is used to find the sum, then the average is calculated and finally, [`Stream.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) is used to find the minimum element of the stream, which is the one that is closest to the average.

`Stream.min` receives a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) as an argument, which has the usual comparator semantics: if the first argument is less than the second one, return a negative value; if greater, return a positive value, otherwise (if equal), return zero. In this case, `a` is less than `b` if its distance to the average is less than `b`'s distance to the average. Here I'm using [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) to perform the comparison.

Note that `Stream.min` doesn't return the minimum number, but an `Optional<Integer>` instead. This is because the `weight` list might be empty, so in this case there would be no minimum element. This is when the [`Optional.ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) method comes in handy: if a minimum has been found, then we remove it from the `weight` list, otherwise nothing happens.